# javascript background image change with php page calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a html with a few 'a' tag which calls a specific pages, I have added an onclick attritbute where the function for the background change occurs depending on the link clicked.
here is the html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=Home " onclick="changeImage(1);">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=Achivement" onclick="changeImage(2); ">Achivement</a></li>

    <li><a href="index.php?page=Career" onclick="changeImage(3); return false;">Career</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=Message" onclick="#">Message</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=opportunity">opportunity</a></li>
    <li><a href="upload1.php">Register</a>
    <li></li>
 </ul>
```

and the javascript file defining the function.

```
function changeImage(number)
{

$.post('core/changebg.php',{number:number},

    function(data)
    {

         $('body').css('background-image','url("image/'+number+'.jpg")');


    });
}
```

and the php file it is referencing

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['number']))
   {

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['image']=$_POST['number'];

  }

if(isset($_GET['resetBg'])){

   session_start();
   session_destroy();
}?>
```

Im stuck because if I empty the href element then this code works exactly the way I wanted but, i want the page call as well and the reason it is not working is because the page already reloads and cant execute function as i am told on other posts. So i want this to work by 1. changing the background image when I click on a link, 2 calling the page contens. I tried redirection through javascript but it still would not work. Thank you and any answers/ suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this in the wrong way. You need to:

1. Let the click event progress as expected and change the background image by either by applying a class to the `body` (preferred), inline-styling the `body` (worse) or calling the JavaScript on load (worst).
2. Load the content via AJAX and skip the page refresh altogether.

Looking at what you're doing above, the second option is likely not a great option for you. Your current AJAX call is weird, as it doesn't seem to do anything at all with the data returned from the server. Maybe you're already using the clicked link information that you're putting into session? I can't really tell.